# Laravel import Seller_id from Excel File

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm building multi Shops Platform, So i'm able to manage shop's products from admin panel

i'm using [this package](https://github.com/maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) to import products from excel file to specific Shop, and i've Shop_id in Products Table

Now, I'm able to import excel file to database successfully. But, The problem is to assign Shop_id in for each product

Any Ideas to do that ?

PruductImport.php

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product([
            'name'         => $row['Name'],
            'price'        => $row['Price'],
        ]);
    }
```

Controller

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new PruductImport,request()->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success','Done!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductImport ...
{
    protected $shop_id;

    public function __construct($shop_id)
    {
        $this->shop_id = $shop_id;
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product([
            'name'         => $row['Name'],
            'price'        => $row['Price'],
            'shop_id'      => $this->shop_id,
        ]);
    } 
}

/// how to create a new instance and pass the shop id

new ProductImport($shop_id)

// in the Controller

Excel::import(new PruductImport($shop_id), request()->file('file'));
```

Comment: is there any changes to do in controller? cause this not work

Comment: yea, the last line above ...  you have to pass the store id to the new instance of the ProductImport you are creating, since you just added that to the constructor so it can be used later

Comment: i think i did something wrong 
could you please give me a full code example of the controller

Comment: it shows this error now
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: and now you are dealing with foreign key constraints on the database ... the `shop_id` that is used must exist in the database